# Updating the metrics in TensorFlow separately

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have written a custom metrics:

```
class ReidClassificationAccuracy(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="accuracy_position_distance_thresholding", with_visibility=False, with_occlusion=False,
                 params={}, **kwargs):
        super(ReidClassificationAccuracy, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.accuracy = self.add_weight(name="accuracy", initializer="zeros")
        self.num_samples = self.add_weight(name="num_samples", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, pids, cls_score_list, sample_weight=None):
        overall_cls_score = 0
        for cls_score in cls_score_list:
            overall_cls_score += cls_score
        self.accuracy = self.compute_accuracy(overall_cls_score, pids, [1])[0]
        return self.accuracy

    def result(self):
        return self.accuracy / self.num_samples

    def reset_states(self):
        self.accuracy.assign(0.)
        self.num_samples.assign(0.)

    def compute_accuracy(self, output, target, topk=[1]):
        """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
        maxk = max(topk)
        batch_size = target.size(0)

        _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
        pred = pred.t()
        correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))

        res = []
        for k in topk:
            correct_k = correct[:k].view(-1).float().sum(0, keepdim=True)
            res.append(correct_k)
        return res
```

Now, as its inputs are different from other metrics and are not y_pred and y_trues, I want to update the state of this metric separately. Currently, I update the metrics using:

```
model.compiled_metrics.update_state(y_trues, y_preds)  # Update metrics
```

However, I cannot separately update the Reid metrics. I have tried to write it in a for loop, but the model.compiled_metrics is not iterable.